# How to insert fontified git diff output into Emacs buffer?

Tags: font-lock, shell-command

I wrote this code:

```el
(defun compare-string-test (String1 String2)
  (interactive)
  (let ((Temp1 (make-temp-file "gitdiff" nil nil String1))
        (Temp2 (make-temp-file "gitdiff" nil nil String2)))

    (insert
     (with-temp-buffer
       (insert
        (shell-command-to-string
         (format
          "git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. %s %s"
          Temp1 Temp2)))
       (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
       (buffer-string)))))
```

I tried:

```el
(compare-string-test "Ciao" "Miao")
```

I'd like to insert a "fontified" string but it doesn't work.

If I remove the `ansi-color-apply-on-region` command I get:

```
[1mdiff --git a/tmp/gitdiffM8px4W b/tmp/gitdiffb5aHy4[m
[1mindex 11d8bbf..cf44f4e 100644[m
[1m--- a/tmp/gitdiffM8px4W[m
[1m+++ b/tmp/gitdiffb5aHy4[m
[36m@@ -1 +1 @@[m
[31mC[m[32mM[miao
```

and if I evaluate `(ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))` I get:

[image]

that it's what I need (I'm only interested in the last line).

How can I make my function inserting the string with this fontification?

Referring to this https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/56223/15606, I tried the function both with `font-lock-mode` active and disabled.

I also tried `message` instead of `insert` but the massage in the minibuffer appears without fontification.

I red the `buffer-string` and `insert` documentation and I think these functions should keep text properties.

**Note.** I also opened an issue to ask for a solution using `elisp` tools only: [Is there an Emacs function or package to visually compare two text strings?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/80513/15606)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stemmed from the fact that by default, `ansi-color-apply-on-region` does not use **text-properties** to color the text but instead employs **overlays**. This behavior is controlled by the variable `ansi-color-apply-face-function`, which on my machine was indeed set by default to `ansi-color-apply-overlay-face`.

> (ansi-color-apply-on-region *BEGIN* *END* &optional *PRESERVE-SEQUENCES*)
>
> Translates SGR control sequences into overlays or extents. Delete all
> other control sequences without processing them.
>
> SGR control sequences are applied by calling the function specified by
> ‘`ansi-color-apply-face-function`’.  The default function sets
> foreground and background colors to the text between *BEGIN* and *END*,
> using overlays.  See function ‘`ansi-color-apply-sequence`’ for details.

The following code works as expected for me:

```el
(defun compare-string-test (String1 String2)
  (interactive)
  (let ((Temp1 (make-temp-file "gitdiff" nil nil String1))
        (Temp2 (make-temp-file "gitdiff" nil nil String2))
        (ansi-color-apply-face-function 'ansi-color-apply-text-property-face))
    (insert
     (with-temp-buffer
       (insert
        (shell-command-to-string
         (format
          "git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. %s %s"
          Temp1 Temp2)))
       (ansi-color-apply-on-region (point-min) (point-max))
       (buffer-string)))))
```